# npm link only dist folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-link

Is there a way to restrict `npm link` to create the symlink only to point at `./dist`?

I am struggling so far as I want to test my library (react component) locally before publishing.

In my `package.json` I have included the main (entry point):

```js
"main": "./dist/index.js"
```

But still when I run `npm link` it links to the parent folder which has `node_modules` and so on.
This is causing problems cause now I have 2 react apps installed.

I thought of a way to exclude `node_modules` but I couldn't even find a way to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually simpler than expected. First run **ng build** to build your library project, then go under the dist folder and run **npm lin**k from there instead of the library root project. The symlink will be created pointing to the dist folder instead.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution and you are a beautiful person. This made my day :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me... it links the parent folder

Comment: doesn't work for me either :(

Comment: Doesn't work here. Still linking everrything.

Answer (score -2):

Using "main" parameter doesn't make sense because npm link use 'npm prefix' for create symlink 
[see here](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/797a59797a2e226631f068c912f351ba340581fe/lib/link.js#L54)

You can use next hack:

1. Cd to project directory
2. Copy package.json from package to ./dist/package.json directory
3. Cd to dist directory
4. Run 'npm link'

It looks dirty but seem to only way to do it with npm link

Comment: Well yeah I didn't wanna go down that road :D Thank you tho

Comment: if you can use additional tools then you may try using [lerna link](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/link) You necessary to add in package.json (in root level) next lines:

    "publishConfig": {
        "directory": "dist"
      }

Comment: Beyond "looking dirty," it won't work in anything but the most basic projects. Any sort of relative import path, for example, will explode.