# How to set up a NPM Typescript package during development to maintain import syntax?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am developing a NPM typescript package to code-split from my main application.

The two projects share a root directory, i.e.:

```
- mylib
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - src/
  - dist/
- myapp
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
  - src/
```

If `myapp/package.json` attempts to link `mylib` as `file:../mylib`, then `npm install` succeeds... but the only way I can succesfully import is to use `... from mylib/src/` (otherwise, the `tsc` compiler does not recognize the path). However, this import syntax differs from the production version of the package (which would not include `src`).

Plus, I need to be able to also develop `mylib` against a second app which is *not* typescript enabled. Including the `src` in the import paths would not work in this scenario, as this path would not resolve against the published NPM package when the application is built by the CI.

I came across [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446361/npm-link-only-dist-folder) which does *technically* work:

```
cd mylib
cp package.json dist/
cd dist
npm link

cd ../../myapp
npm link mylib
```

Thus, the `npm link` is created to the `dist` folder. But it requires copying the `package.json`, otherwise the link just goes to `mylib` rather than `mylib/dist`.

Unfortunately, this quickly falls apart, because my `mylib/package.json` has relative import paths:

```
"react": "file:../myapp/node_modules/react",
```

Which [are necessary in order to preserve only one instance of the React package](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react). Copying the `package.json` into the `dist/` folder to create the link causes these imports to fail to resolve. Using an absolute path would not work for other developers on my project. Besides, copying the `package.json` into the `dist/` seems like an anti-pattern.

### Edit 1

I tried switching to `yarn`, per the comments. It exhibits the exact same behavior as NPM in this regard. Namely, the `yarn link` command always points at the folder with `package.json`. Again, this forces me to use the `src/` folder in my imports, which will not work in a production build pointing at the production NPM packages.

Comment: you may need 'yarn workspaces` or `lerna`, https://github.com/babel/babel.git use lerna,
https://github.com/facebook/react use yarn workspaces, google monorepo to see more details

Comment: I just discovered Lerna as I was researching more. Glad to hear a vote for it. Would you recommend one over the other (yarn vs. lerna)?

Comment: yarn is more easy to use

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, after switching to yarn, I'm having the exact same problem. Namely: the `yarn link` will not let me point at the `dist` folder. The symlink goes to the root of the NPM package, and therefore my import statements require the `src/` path component.

Answer (score 0):

firstly workspaces does not require link
a simple way to solve you prob

```
// packages/project-a/index.ts
// for development
export * from src/index.ts;
```

```js
// packages/project-a/index.js
// for production
module.exports = require('dist/index.js');
```

create a index.js, index.ts in you modules,
when use ts-node to run you project, program will auto load index.tswhen use node to run you project, program will auto load index.js
a better way is compile how project at root, see  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next